# How can I modify the a duplicate id and class with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code, I have two option values ("illinois" and "florida".)

I would like to use jquery to select which information is shown through the div id and class.

I'm trying to modify the id and class with the following jquery:

```js
(function($) {
  $('.select-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
      $targetRow = $this.data('target'),
      $activeClassText = 'active';
    $('.select-button').removeClass($activeClassText);
    $this.addClass($activeClassText);
    $('.members-row').removeClass($activeClassText);
    $('#' + $targetRow + '-members').addClass($activeClassText);
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.members-row,
.tab-select-buttons {
  display: none;
}

.select-area-selection {
  display: block;
}

.selection-of-areas {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 11px 9px 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.5);
}

a.select-button {
  background: #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.7);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 18px 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1;
}

a.select-button.active,
a.select-button:hover,
a.select-button:focus {
  background: #DD4D4D;
  color: #fff;
}

.members-row.active {
  display: block;
}

.tab-select-buttons {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
  -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.select-area-selection {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-select-buttons">
  <a href="#" data-target="illinois" rel="noopener nofollow noreferrer" class="select-button">
   Illinois
  </a>
  <a href="#" data-target="florida" rel="noopener nofollow noreferrer" class="select-button">
   Florida
  </a>

</div>
<div class="select-area-selection">
  <select class="selection-of-areas" id="selection-of-area">
    <option value="illinois">Illinois</option>
    <option value="florida">Florida</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="illinois-members" class="members-row">
  Test Illinois
</div>
<div id="florida-members" class="members-row">
  Test Florida
</div>
<div id="illinois-members" class="members-row">
  Also show this for Illinois
</div>
```

I want to target both of the Illinois divs when I click the "Illinois" option.  But it only pulls one.  I know duplicate ids are wrong to use, so how can I fix this?

Comment: You fix it by not using duplicate ids. Invalid markup is invalid!

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use duplicate IDs- you'll just end up running into trouble ([and it's semantically incorrect - each ID is a unique identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)). In this case classes are perfect- where you have the ID `illinois-members` add a new class named `illinois-members` and change your selector to search for that.

Changes in HTML:

```html
<div class="illinois-members members-row">
  Test Illinois
</div>
<div class="florida-members members-row">
  Test Florida
</div>
<div class="illinois-members members-row">
  Also show this for Illinois
</div>
```

Changes in JS:

Before:

```js
    $('#' + $targetRow + '-members').addClass($activeClassText);
```

After:

```js
    $('.' + $targetRow + '-members').addClass($activeClassText);
```